# Jenkins Git Parameter Plugin branchFilter regex

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-git-plugin

I am using Git Parameter Plugin (0.9.12) for Jenkins declarative pipeline here as below. The output of `params.branchName` is **master** where output needs to **origin/master** for my case.

Is there anyway to do this ? How can I add get the **origin/master** output from params.brancName.

```
parameters {    
    gitParameter branchFilter: 'origin/(.*)', defaultValue: 'master', name: 'branchName', type: 'PT_BRANCH'
} 

stages {
    stage('Git clone and environment setup') {
        steps{
            
            git branch: "${params.branchName}", credentialsId: 'xxx', url: 'https://git.xxxx.git'

            echo 'Git paramater...' +  params.branchName
            // Git paramater...master. ->> **Which I need is origin/master**

        }
    }

    stage ('Run Tests for Dev ') {
        when {
            beforeAgent true
            expression { params.branchName == "origin/development"}
        }
```

Here is configuration for branches to build.
[image: Configuration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```yaml
parameters {
        gitParameter name: 'branchName', 
                     type: 'PT_BRANCH',
                     defaultValue: 'master'
    }

stages {
    stage('Git clone and environment setup') {
        steps{
            script {
            echo "Git paramater is ${params.branchName}"
            git branch: "${params.branchName}", credentialsId: 'xxx', url: 'https://git.xxxx.git'

            }

        }
    }

    stage ('Run Tests for Dev ') {
        when {
            beforeAgent true
            expression { "${params.branchName}" == "origin/development"}
        }
      }
```

I tried the same code. It worked for me:

[image]
[image]

Comment: shall I use the same parameter plugin again ? How should parameter look like ?

Comment: Cause when I checkout it always use the defaultValue branch which should be the branch that I am checking out.

Comment: May I know, form your question. What is the value of this parameter **${params.branchName}** ? Is it master or something else.

Comment: master.. But ı would like to set this dynimacally.. ıf ı check origin/development then it should be origin/development

Comment: and what should be the branchspecifier in jenkins configuration

Comment: I forgot to add the gitParameter, please check i have edited the answer.

Comment: How did you configure Branches to build -> Branch Specifier (blank for 'any') in configuration ? ı added my current configuration in question

Comment: Could you please share the ss of our job configuration ? How did you fill the branch specifier ?